# In NavigationView, List item appears mid-screen rather than at top when @Environment(\.presentationMode) is defined

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

I'm facing a weird bug where a list item within a NavigationView appears below a gap. When I scroll, it resets to correct location.

[image: Screen Capture]

Minimum reproducible example on Xcode 14.1, iOS 16.1.2:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Test_2022_12_03_02App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ListView()
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                Text("Hello")
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    // If I remove the line below, the bug disappears
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var members = [1]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(members, id:\.self) { member in
                Text("World")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This bug happens consistently on my phone, but doesn't always happen in simulators. Weirdly my friend's phone also displayed expected behavior with same iOS version.

More notes:

- If I remove `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode` the bug disappears. (I need this line for my full app, to  be able to return to main screen from the navigation link)
- The bug also disappears if in the DetailView, we don't use a List, i.e.

```
struct DetailView: View {
    // If I remove the line below, the bug disappears
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var members = [1]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
//            ForEach(members, id:\.self) { member in
                Text("World")
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

Two questions:

- Do you know what's happening? Am I missing something in my code?
- If this is a freak bug, how do I find a workaround? Note that I need both the list and the ability to return to main screen in my full app.

Thanks!

Comment: I just started noticing this too, after installing 16.1.2. Similarly appears to be affected if you navigated from a List or not.

Answer (score -1):

NavigationView is deprecated and so is presentationMode. There is bound to be unforeseen bugs using deprecated methods. Use navigation stack instead: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack

Comment: That's iOS 16 only. iOS 16 has around 50% penetration, so it's not ideal

Comment: False. It is not deprecated. It will be in the future but it's not yet.